# Как уменьшить кнопки telegram api?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Хочу сделать такие кнопки:

[image: Кнопки, которые хочу]

Код C#:

```
var chatId = message.Chat.Id;
var list = new List<KeyboardButton>() { new KeyboardButton("Пополнить баланс"), new 
KeyboardButton("\U0001F3E0Главное меню") };
var markup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup(list);
await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, "Hi!", replyMarkup: markup);
```

Получаются такие:

[image: Кнопки, которые получаются]

Comment: В библиотеке на питоне за маленькие кнопки отвечает параметр `resize_keyboard=True`: https://github.com/gil9red/telegram__random_bashim_bot/blob/9f3c8ae9b224f6d851ab7c7fa7113f3ca2fccb92/common.py#L97 . Наверняка, этот параметр можно и в `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` указывать

Comment: @gil9red да! Это то что я искал. Нужно было просто написать так ReplyKeyboardMarkup(list, true).

Comment: Оформите, пожалуйста, сами как ответ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для конструктора объекта ReplyKeyboardMarkup существует параметр resizeKeyboard (подробнее в [документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup)). Для решения проблемы можно просто заменить

```
var markup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup(list);
```

на

```
var markup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup(list, true);
```

Comment: Для nuget Telegram.Bot, v.18.0.0: `var markup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup(list) { ResizeKeyboard = true };`